# Recursion, Truncation, and "coding."

Tags: logic, computability, recursion

The example is "left to the reader", but I am having trouble approaching this problem.

There is a primitive recursive function $tr$ such that if $s$ codes a sequence $(a_{0},...,a_{n-1})$, and $m\le n$, then $tr(s,m)$ codes the truncated sequence $(a_{0},...,a_{m-1})$

How does one go about showing that this is primitive recursive? My text defines primitive recursion as follows $$h(x,0)=f(x),h(x,s(y))=g(x,y,h(x,y)).$$

Thank you for any help in advance!

Edit: The text says "The coding we adopt is based on the fact that each positive interger can be written in one and only one way as a product of powers of larger and larger primes. Specifically: $(a_{0},...,a_{n-1})$ is coded by $2^{n}\cdot 3^{a_{0}} \cdot 5^{a_{1}}\cdots \pi (n)^{a_{n-1}}$"

Comment: What is meant by "codes"?

Comment: Yeah, that is part of my problem as well. My text never explicitly defines what it means by codes. Rather, it just starts to use it. (lol) I will look through the text really quick and see what I might be able to salvage and edit my question.

Comment: Whats the book/page number? It might be on google books

Comment: Computability and Logic (5th Edition Boolos) pg.84

Comment: Here's what I'm guessing: $S$ is a function which returns a list of length $n$, and $tr$ is supposed to truncate it to the first $m$ elements

Comment: I suppose that "codes" need not be specified further than this: $(s,k)\mapsto a_k$ and $(s,a)\mapsto s'$ are primitive recursive, where $s$ "encodes" $(a_0,\ldots,a_{n-1})$ and $s'$ "endcodes" $(a_0,\ldots,a_{n-1},a)$

Comment: Okay, I'm going to make an edit and show where the closest thing I see can see as a definition for coding in my text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need an *encoding* scheme for a sequence $\langle a_0, \ldots, a_{n-1} \rangle$ of *numbers*.

According to BBJ's encoding, page 79 :

> $s= 2^n3^{a_0} \ldots \pi(n)^{a_{n-1}}$

With this encoding, we have that :

> $lh(s)=lo(s,2)$, where $lo(x,y)$ is the greatest $z ≤ x$ such that $y^z$ divides $x$ if $x, y > 1$,

i.e. the "lenght" of $s$,

and :

> $ent(s,i)=lo(s,\pi(i+1))$, for $0 < i <n$,

i.e. $ent(s,i)=a_i$,

are the "deconding" functions.

Thus:

> > $tr(s,m)=2^m\Pi_{0 < i < m} \pi(i)^{ent(s,i)}$

Answer (score 2):

The base case

$tr(s, 0) = first(s)$

The recursive case

$tr(s, m) = first(s) \oplus tr(rest(s), m - 1)$

Where $first(s)$ returns the first item in a list $s$

and

$rest(s)$ returns a list of everything but the first element

$\oplus $ appends lists